# MySQL - Sum rows in one column based on values in another column - grouped - using variables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum data based on the values in one column grouped by the values in another column.

Specifically I am trying to sum data so that cumesum is reset to zero when the Ref column changes as in the below image.

[image: Required Result]

I can do this with this conventional query but it is too slow for a large recordset:

```
select LengthsBtn, Ref, HorseNo,
   (select sum(r2.LengthsBtn) from Runners r2 where r2.Fin_Pos <= r.Fin_Pos and r2.ref = r.ref) as cumesum from Runners r;
```

To speed this is up i am trying to use variables to make the same thing happen but i cannot figure out how to reset the variable to zero when the Ref changes using this query:

```
select Fin_Pos, HorseNo, Ref,
   (@sum := @sum + r.LengthsBtn) as cumesum from RUNNERS r cross join
 (select @sum := 0) params order by Ref, Fin_Pos;
```

However this query returns the results as below and is creating a cumulative column.

[image: Wrong Result]

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sample data and expected results *as text* not images would help

Comment: What version?  See Windowing functions in 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of MySQL you can use a windowed running sum. You simply put the `Ref` column as the partitioning column, to calculate it individually per `Ref`.

```
select
  Fin_Pos,
  HorseNo,
  Ref,
  sum(r.LengthsBtn) over (partition by Ref order by Fin_Pos rows unbounded preceding) as cumesum
from RUNNERS r 
order by
  Ref,
  Fin_Pos;
```

Do not be tempted to use variables like you have, it can cause incorrect results and has undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is really helpful - I have been using 5.6 I will upgrade and test but assume your solution to be correct - thank you for your help on this much appreciated